# How can I properly send a command to Maya using os.getcwd() in Python

Tags: python, string, macos

So I'm using sockets to send some output to maya. Unfortunately what I'm getting back from Maya doesn't make sense at all. I'm trying to quote a variable, while escaping the quote, but once it gets to Maya it fails. Here's the code:

```
currentDir = os.getcwd()
maya.send('python("import os; import sys; os.chdir(\''+currentDir+'\'); sys.path.append(\''+currentDir+'\'); import pythonExec; pythonExec.main()")')
```

Here's the output I get:

```
python("import os; import sys; os.chdir('C:\Users\pneumonic\Documents\My Dropbox\pythonTesting'); sys.path.append('C:\Users\pneumonic\Documents\My Dropbox\pythonTesting'); import pythonExec; pythonExec.main()");
import os; import sys; os.chdir('C:UserspneumonicDocumentsMy DropboxpythonTesting'); sys.path.append('C:UserspneumonicDocumentsMy DropboxpythonTesting'); import pythonExec; pythonExec.main()
# Error: line 1: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified: 'C:UserspneumonicDocumentsMy DropboxpythonTesting'
# Traceback (most recent call last):
#   File "<maya console>", line 1, in <module>
# WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified: 'C:UserspneumonicDocumentsMy DropboxpythonTesting' #
```

It's dropping every \ character in the path name. I've tried using a double quote instead of a single quote and the output I get from that is this:

```
python("import os; import sys; os.chdir("C:\Users\pneumonic\Documents\My Dropbox\pythonTesting"); sys.path.append("C:\Users\pneumonic\Documents\My Dropbox\pythonTesting"); import pythonExec; pythonExec.main()");
// Error: python("import os; import sys; os.chdir("C:\Users\pneumonic\Documents\My Dropbox\pythonTesting"); sys.path.append("C:\Users\pneu€ // 
// Error: Line 1.42: Syntax error //
```

I'm not sure what it is I'm doing wrong, but it's obviously something on my part. Thanks for the help in advance.

sidenote- I do most of my development on OSX and everything works perfectly on there and I'm not doing anything that's os specific so I'm confused as to why I'm having so many issues with windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ended up being a very simple fix:

```
path = os.getcwd()
convertPath = path.replace('\\','/')
```

I take no credit for the answer though. I got the answer from http://forums.cgsociety.org/showpost.php?p=6890246&postcount=2 from r4inm4ker. :)